# Django - Mascara CPF, DDD e número do telefone

Tags: jquery, python, django

Preciso colocar máscara na digitação do CPF, DDD e do número do telefone.
Sou iniciante em Python e Django e gostaria de saber como posso apresentar esta máscara no momento da digitação:

Para o CPF: 999.999.999-99.

Para o Telefone: (99) 99999-9999.

Criei somente os arquivos models.py e admin.py e como mágica já tenho formulários funcionais, mas quero melhorar a apresentação colocando a máscara.

O que tenho que fazer?

Onde tenho que colocar esta instrução?

Preciso de algum exemplo se for possível.

models.py

```
class Cliente(models.Model):

    SEXO_CHOICES = (
        ('M', u'Masculino'),
        ('F', u'Feminino'),
    )

    ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES = (
        ('S', u'Solteiro'),
        ('C', u'Casado'),
        ('D', u'Divorciado'),
        ('V', u'Viúvo'),
    )

    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True)
    dtNascimento = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data de nascimento')
    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEXO_CHOICES)
    estado_civil = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ESTADO_CIVIL_CHOICES, verbose_name='Estado civil')
    nrTelCelular = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nº telefone celular')
    nrTelFixo = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Nº telefone fixo')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

admin.py

```
class ClienteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Cliente
    list_display = ['nome','cpf', 'dtNascimento', 'sexo',
                    'estado_civil', 'nrTelCelular', 'nrTelFixo']
    list_filter = ['sexo', 'estado_civil']
    search_fields = ['nome']
admin.site.register(Cliente, ClienteAdmin)
```

Comment: Qual versão do `python` e `django` está utilizando ?

Comment: Python 3 com Django 1.11.4

Comment: [Django Input Mask](https://github.com/caioariede/django-input-mask) Talvez consiga fazer funcionar, mas creio que está obsuleto.

Comment: Mais recomendo o uso [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza, django-input-maks não está obsoleto, o [último commit foi feito em 07/02/17.](https://github.com/caioariede/django-input-mask)

Comment: Eu nem tinha reparado,estava na empresa e lá sabe como é, os caras não gosta muito que fica usando internet.

Comment: Infelizmente é incompatível com Django 2.0

Answer (score 5):

você pode usar o [django-input-mask](https://github.com/caioariede/django-input-mask)

dentro do seu form você pode facilmente criar suas mascaras.

```
from input_mask.widgets import InputMask

class MyCustomInput(InputMask):
   mask = {'cpf': '000.000.000-00'}
```